# Geodesic Equation from energy-momentum conservation

Tags: general-relativity, conservation-laws, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, geodesics

I've been reading the excelent review from Eric Poisson found [here](http://relativity.livingreviews.org/open?pubNo=lrr-2011-7&page=articlese12.html).
While studying it I stumbled in a proof that I can't make... I can't find a way to go from Eq.(19.3) to the one before Eq.(19.4) (which is unnumbered).

I've been able to do some progress (which I present below), but can't get the right answer... Please somebody help me. It's getting really frustating...

Thank you

Given the energy-momentum tensor$$T^{\alpha\beta}\left(x\right)=m{\displaystyle \int_{\gamma}\frac{g^{\alpha}{}_{\mu}\left(x,z\right)g^{\beta}{}_{\nu}\left(x,z\right)\dot{z}^{\mu}\dot{z}^{\nu}}{\sqrt{-g_{\alpha\beta}\dot{z}^{\alpha}\dot{z}^{\nu}}}\delta_{4}\left(x,z\right)d\lambda,}$$

one can take it's divergence\begin{alignedat}{1}\nabla_{\beta}T^{\alpha\beta} & =m{\displaystyle \int_{\gamma}\nabla_{\beta}\left[\frac{g^{\alpha}{}_{\mu}g^{\beta}{}_{\nu}\dot{z}^{\mu}\dot{z}^{\nu}}{\sqrt{-g_{\alpha\beta}\dot{z}^{\alpha}\dot{z}^{\nu}}}\delta_{4}\left(x,z\right)\right]d\lambda}=\\
 & =m{\displaystyle \int_{\gamma}\nabla_{\beta}\left[\frac{g^{\alpha}{}_{\mu}g^{\beta}{}_{\nu}\dot{z}^{\mu}\dot{z}^{\nu}}{\sqrt{-g_{\alpha\beta}\dot{z}^{\alpha}\dot{z}^{\nu}}}\right]\delta_{4}\left(x,z\right)d\lambda+m{\displaystyle \int_{\gamma}\frac{g^{\alpha}{}_{\mu}g^{\beta}{}_{\nu}\dot{z}^{\mu}\dot{z}^{\nu}}{\sqrt{-g_{\alpha\beta}\dot{z}^{\alpha}\dot{z}^{\nu}}}\nabla_{\beta}\left[\delta_{4}\left(x,z\right)\right]d\lambda.}}
\end{alignedat}

But using Eq.13.3 of the reference one finds that the divergence of the energy-momentum tensor is also given by\begin{alignedat}{1}\nabla_{\beta}T^{\alpha\beta} & =m{\displaystyle \int_{\gamma}\nabla_{\beta}\left[\frac{g^{\alpha}{}_{\mu}g^{\beta}{}_{\nu}\dot{z}^{\mu}\dot{z}^{\nu}}{\sqrt{-g_{\alpha\beta}\dot{z}^{\alpha}\dot{z}^{\nu}}}\delta_{4}\left(x,z\right)\right]d\lambda}=\\
 & =m{\displaystyle \int_{\gamma}\nabla_{\beta}\left[\frac{g^{\alpha}{}_{\mu}\dot{z}^{\mu}\dot{z}^{\nu}}{\sqrt{-g_{\alpha\beta}\dot{z}^{\alpha}\dot{z}^{\nu}}}\right]g^{\beta}{}_{\nu}\delta_{4}\left(x,z\right)d\lambda-m{\displaystyle \int_{\gamma}\frac{g^{\alpha}{}_{\mu}\dot{z}^{\mu}\dot{z}^{\nu}}{\sqrt{-g_{\alpha\beta}\dot{z}^{\alpha}\dot{z}^{\nu}}}\nabla_{\nu}\left[\delta_{4}\left(x,z\right)\right]d\lambda,}}
\end{alignedat}

Which means that$$m{\displaystyle \int_{\gamma}\frac{g^{\alpha}{}_{\mu}g^{\beta}{}_{\nu}\dot{z}^{\mu}\dot{z}^{\nu}}{\sqrt{-g_{\alpha\beta}\dot{z}^{\alpha}\dot{z}^{\nu}}}\nabla_{\beta}\left[\delta_{4}\left(x,z\right)\right]d\lambda=-m{\displaystyle \int_{\gamma}\frac{g^{\alpha}{}_{\mu}\dot{z}^{\mu}\dot{z}^{\nu}}{\sqrt{-g_{\alpha\beta}\dot{z}^{\alpha}\dot{z}^{\nu}}}\nabla_{\nu}\left[\delta_{4}\left(x,z\right)\right]d\lambda,}}$$

so it must be zero (please correct me if I'm wrong).

Then, using Eqs.(5.14) and (13.3), the divergence of the energy-momentum tensor is simply\begin{alignedat}{1}\nabla_{\beta}T^{\alpha\beta} & =m{\displaystyle \int_{\gamma}\nabla_{\beta}\left[\frac{g^{\alpha}{}_{\mu}g^{\beta}{}_{\nu}\dot{z}^{\mu}\dot{z}^{\nu}}{\sqrt{-g_{\alpha\beta}\dot{z}^{\alpha}\dot{z}^{\nu}}}\right]\delta_{4}\left(x,z\right)d\lambda}=\\
 & =m{\displaystyle \int_{\gamma}\frac{D}{d\lambda}\left[\frac{g^{\alpha}{}_{\mu}\dot{z}^{\mu}}{\sqrt{-g_{\alpha\beta}\dot{z}^{\alpha}\dot{z}^{\nu}}}\right]\delta_{4}\left(x,z\right)d\lambda}+\\
 & \,\,\,+m{\displaystyle \int_{\gamma}\frac{g^{\alpha}{}_{\mu}\dot{z}^{\mu}}{\sqrt{-g_{\alpha\beta}\dot{z}^{\alpha}\dot{z}^{\nu}}}\nabla_{\beta}\left[g^{\beta}{}_{\nu}\dot{z}^{\nu}\right]\delta_{4}\left(x,z\right)d\lambda.}
\end{alignedat}

If what I've done is correct then comparing with the reference's result the last term must be zero. Can anyone think why?

I thought that, since the covariant derivative is taken in the point $x$
  then $g^{\beta}{}_{\nu}\nabla_{\beta}\dot{z}^{\nu}$
  is zero but then, what forbids $g^{\alpha}{}_{\mu}g^{\beta}{}_{\nu}\dot{z}^{\nu}\nabla_{\beta}\dot{z}^{\mu}$
  to be equally zero?

Comment: Eric Poisson link broken . try this  ?   http://www.fulviofrisone.com/attachments/article/471/Poisson,%20Eric%20-%20An%20advanced%20course%20in%20general%20relativity(190s)(T).pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will abuse notation a little, but I hope you don't find it terrible. After all, I only abuse notation: not children!

**Trick 1: Parametrize by Proper Length.** We will pick for our affine parameter $\lambda=s$ the proper length. Then the stress energy tensor becomes
$$\tag{1}T^{\alpha\beta}(x)=m\int_{\gamma}u^{\alpha} u^{\beta}\frac{\delta^{(4)}\bigl(x,z(s)\bigr)}{\sqrt{|g|}}\,\mathrm{d}s$$ 
where $u^{\alpha}=\mathrm{d}x^{\alpha}/\mathrm{d}s$ and $g=\det{g_{\mu\nu}}$.

**Trick 2: Covariant Derivative Trick.** We can write
$$\nabla_{\mu}f^{\mu}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{|g|}}\partial_{\mu}(\sqrt{|g|}f^{\mu})$$
for arbitrary $f^{\mu}$.

**Exercise:** Using Poisson's notation [(13.2)](http://relativity.livingreviews.org/open?pubNo=lrr-2011-7&page=articlese13.html), we have
$$\delta(x,x') = \frac{\delta^{(4)}(x-x')}{\sqrt{|g|}} = \frac{\delta^{(4)}(x-x')}{\sqrt{|g'|}}$$
and thus using our Covariant Derivative trick, find
$$\nabla_{\mu}\delta(x,x')=???$$

This will tell you that
$$\int u^{\alpha}u^{\beta}\nabla_{\alpha}\delta(x,x')\,\mathrm{d}s = \mbox{boundary terms}$$
and thus we can ignore it.

**Remark 1.** You are in error writing
\begin{alignedat}{1}\nabla_{\beta}T^{\alpha\beta} & =m{\displaystyle \int_{\gamma}\nabla_{\beta}\left[\frac{g^{\alpha}{}_{\mu}g^{\beta}{}_{\nu}\dot{z}^{\mu}\dot{z}^{\nu}}{\sqrt{-g_{\alpha\beta}\dot{z}^{\alpha}\dot{z}^{\nu}}}\delta_{4}\left(x,z\right)\right]d\lambda}=\\
 & =m{\displaystyle \int_{\gamma}\nabla_{\beta}\left[\frac{g^{\alpha}{}_{\mu}g^{\beta}{}_{\nu}\dot{z}^{\mu}\dot{z}^{\nu}}{\sqrt{-g_{\alpha\beta}\dot{z}^{\alpha}\dot{z}^{\nu}}}\right]\delta_{4}\left(x,z\right)d\lambda-m{\displaystyle \int_{\gamma}\frac{g^{\alpha}{}_{\mu}g^{\beta}{}_{\nu}\dot{z}^{\mu}\dot{z}^{\nu}}{\sqrt{-g_{\alpha\beta}\dot{z}^{\alpha}\dot{z}^{\nu}}}\nabla_{\nu}\left[\delta_{4}\left(x,z\right)\right]d\lambda,}}
\end{alignedat}
This should have been a simple application of the product rule. That is, the minus sign should be a plus sign.

**Remark 2.** Why should we expect the right hand side of $\nabla_{\beta}T^{\alpha\beta}=0$? Well, because using Einstein's field equation it's $\nabla_{\beta}G^{\alpha\beta}$ and this is *identically zero*.

This is why we set
$$\tag{2}m\int_{\gamma}\nabla_{\beta}\left[\frac{g^{\alpha}{}_{\mu}g^{\beta}{}_{\nu}\dot{z}^{\mu}\dot{z}^{\nu}}{\sqrt{-g_{\alpha\beta}\dot{z}^{\alpha}\dot{z}^{\nu}}}\right]\delta\bigl(x,z\bigr)\,\mathrm{d}\lambda=0.$$
...which is precisely the geodesic equation for a point particle as discussed in Poisson's article [section 3](http://relativity.livingreviews.org/open?pubNo=lrr-2011-7&page=articlese13.html).

**Edit**
We can rewrite (2) since ${g^{\alpha}}_{\beta}={\delta^{\alpha}}_{\beta}$ is the Kronecker delta. So
$$\tag{3}m\int_{\gamma}\nabla_{\nu}\left[\frac{\dot{z}^{\alpha}\dot{z}^{\nu}}{\sqrt{-g_{\alpha\beta}\dot{z}^{\alpha}\dot{z}^{\beta}}}\right]\delta\bigl(x,z\bigr)\,\mathrm{d}\lambda=0.$$
But if we pick the arclength as the parameter, this becomes simply
$$\tag{4}m\int_{\gamma}\nabla_{\nu}(u^{\alpha}u^{\nu})\delta\bigl(x,z\bigr)\,\mathrm{d}\lambda=0.$$
Great, but really is
$$\tag{5}\nabla_{\nu}(u^{\alpha}u^{\nu})=0?$$
Lets recall for a geodesic using arclength parametrization we have
$$u_{\mu}u^{\mu}=1\implies u_{\mu}\nabla_{\nu}u^{\mu}=0.$$
Thus (5), when contracted by a non-negative vector (say $u_{\alpha}$) becomes
\begin{alignedat}{1}u_{\alpha}\nabla_{\nu}(u^{\alpha}u^{\nu}) &= u_{\alpha}\underbrace{u^{\nu}\nabla_{\nu}u^{\alpha}}_{=0} + \underbrace{u_{\alpha}u^{\alpha}}_{=1}\nabla_{\nu}u^{\nu}\\
&=\nabla_{\nu}u^{\nu}\end{alignedat}
But this is a continuity-type equation (and if you use trick 2, it really resembles electromagnetism's continuity equation!).

Now we can go back, and by inspection we find
$$\nabla_{\nu}(u^{\alpha}u^{\nu})=\left(\begin{array}{c}\mbox{Geodesic}\\
\mbox{Equation}\end{array}\right)+\left(\begin{array}{c}\mbox{Continuity}\\
\mbox{Equation}\end{array}\right).$$
This is, of course, $\nabla_{\mu}T^{\mu\nu}$. Why should we expect it to be zero?

Well, if the Einstein field equations hold, then
$$G^{\mu\nu}-\kappa T^{\mu\nu}=0$$
and moreover
$$\nabla_{\mu}(G^{\mu\nu}-\kappa T^{\mu\nu})=0.$$
However, $\nabla_{\mu}G^{\mu\nu}=0$ **identically** thanks to geometry.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry I wrote my equations wrong. I copy pasted them and forgot to edit.
I wasn't understanding what you meant by product rule since I've done it in the first divergence. It was because the second time I took the divergence I wrote the equation wrong.

I believe that what you did is more rigorous but what I did at the very least isn't wrong. I find the same equation you did in the end but my problem is to figure how come that is the  geodesic equation...

Thank you for your time

Comment: @PML: I've updated my post with reasoning I was taught as far as "conservation law for point particle gives the geodesic equation". It answers your question, using a few tricks and slightly different notation; the short answer is: continuity type equation + geodesic equation = that last equation you've got.

Comment: Thank you for your time and explaination. To tie things up: after your very nice presentation you basically say that the expression before Eq.(19.4), which is unnumbered, in Poisson review misses the continuity equation, right?

Comment: Right, which is why it appears as "bonus parts" which --- unless explained as a continuity equation --- seems problematical. ***Extra Point:*** when you include the electromagnetic field coupled to the point particle, you get the Lorentz force for free from the conservation of the stress-energy tensor. This miracle should be worked out by the reader!

Comment: This is indeed excinting and really appears out of nowhere! Was that result known?I'm going to try to work out the details of what you're saying.

Comment: Well, the equation in question (Eq.3) is somehow like a navier-stokes equation for a pressureless fluid and no sources of stress. The term you call continuity is somehow a force (more exactly a force density) but then, what force?

Comment: Well, the continuity equation is an honest continuity equation when we work with a *continuous number* of particles; i.e., when we work with a perfect pressure-less fluid. The resemblance with the Navier-Stokes is no coincidence! As far as where to find this stuff, see MTW. I can give a more precise reference when I get back home...

Comment: Thank you sir. You've been of great help. Thank you, really.

I'll take a look to the MTW book and try to understand this results.

Comment: @PML: Also _Problem Book in Relativity and Gravitation_ has some fantastic exercises on this, which I highly recommend (especially since the solutions are carefully worked out in the book!).

Comment: The first equation is wrong, it should read $$\tag{1}T^{\alpha\beta}(x)=m\int_{\gamma}u^{\alpha} u^{\beta}\frac{\delta^{(4)}\bigl(x-z(s)\bigr)}{\sqrt{|g|}}\,\mathrm{d}s$$. One of the next lines is wrong as well, i.e. $$\int u^{\alpha}u^{\beta}\nabla_{\alpha}\delta(x,x')\,\mathrm{d}s = \mbox{boundary terms}$$ This statement is not true. I found some more errors in your answer. Please revise.

Comment: @jac Your objection to the first equation is difference in notation, not error.  In point of fact, you are in error, if you bother looking at the linked [review article](http://relativity.livingreviews.org/open?pubNo=lrr-2011-7&page=articlese13.html).

Comment: The notation used by Eric Poisson $\delta (x,z)$ is a way to define a delta-symbol that behaves like a scalar while getting rid of the $\sqrt{-g}$ in the denominator of the $\delta (x-z)$. You keep the factor $\sqrt{-g}$ in the denominator of $\delta (x,z)$, which does not make sense. If you work out the second formula, you will see that apart form the boundary terms, another term arises.