# Some aspect of covariant derivative of point particle energy-momentum tensor

Tags: general-relativity, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, geodesics

My question is related to [Derivation of the geodesic equation from the continuity equation for the energy momentum tensor](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/303773/derivation-of-the-geodesic-equation-from-the-continuity-equation-for-the-energy/304269#comment1087149_304269)

I need to understand one step in derivation.

Let's consider the Energy-momentum tensor of point particle:
\begin{equation}\label{1}
 T^{\mu\nu}(x) = \frac{m}{\sqrt{-g(x)}}\int d\tau \frac{dX^{\mu}}{d\tau}\frac{dX^{\nu}}{d\tau}\delta^{(4)}(x - X(\tau))
\end{equation}

We want to find a covariant derivative of $T^{\mu\nu}$. For arbitrary symmetric tensor, the covariant derivative is:
\begin{equation}\label{2}
 \nabla_{\mu} T^{\mu\nu} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{-g}} \frac{\partial \left( \sqrt{-g} T^{\mu\nu}\right) }{\partial x^{\mu}} + \Gamma^{\nu}_{\mu\lambda}T^{\mu\lambda}
\end{equation}

And for our case, let's consider derivative $\frac{1}{\sqrt{-g(x)}} \frac{\partial \left( \sqrt{-g(x)} T^{\mu\nu}\right) }{\partial x^{\mu}}$:

\begin{multline}
 \frac{1}{\sqrt{-g(x)}} \frac{\partial \left( \sqrt{-g(x)} T^{\mu\nu}\right) }{\partial x^{\mu}} = \\
= \frac{1}{\sqrt{-g(x)}} m \int d\tau \frac{dX^{\mu}}{d\tau}\frac{dX^{\nu}}{d\tau}\frac{\partial }{\partial x^{\mu}} \left[ \delta^{(4)}(x - X(\tau))\right] = \\
 = - \frac{1}{\sqrt{-g(x)}} m \int d\tau \frac{dX^{\mu}}{d\tau}\frac{dX^{\nu}}{d\tau}\frac{\partial}{\partial X^{\mu}} \left[  \delta^{(4)}(x - X(\tau)) \right] = \\  
 = - \frac{1}{\sqrt{-g(x)}} m \int d\tau \frac{dX^{\nu}}{d\tau}\frac{d}{d\tau}\left[ \delta^{(4)}(x - X(\tau))\right] = ?\\
\end{multline}

What correct property of $\delta$-function should I use for the next step? Intergrating by parth I think is no completely correct.

Comment: Why do you think integration by parts is not correct?

Comment: I think I get $\frac{dX}{d\tau}\delta(x- X(\tau))$ outside integral, which is undefined.

Comment: Integration by parts with derivatives of the delta function should give you derivatives of the other part of the integrand, as the delta function is 0 at any nonzero point so you don't have delta's outside the integral.

Comment: @Quantumness out of integral $\int udv = uv - \int vdu$ we have $uv = \left.\frac{dX}{d\tau}\delta(x- X(\tau))\right|_{-\infty}^{\infty}$, so, you assert that it is equal to zero? Am I right?

Comment: I believe so, but it depends on the specific values of $x$ and $X$ (how are you defining them?): as long as the difference is not zero the delta function will be zero.

Comment: @Quantumness I define $x$ as arbitrary  point of space-time, and $X$ as a coordinare of particle.

Comment: And I think, instead use of term "integrating by parts" it is simple to use "definition of delta-function derivative" which is $\int u d\delta = \int \delta du$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP is right. Integration by parts leads to boundary terms at the initial and final point of the geodesic worldline. These become creation & annihilation source terms for the energy-momentum continuity equation. I updated [my Phys.SE answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/304269/2451) accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

This expression is defined only if the right is 0 (as it should be in GR). The problem is that the product of generalized functions is poorly defined (non-associative), therefore, multiplying this expression on any function is impossible, but, from another side, it should be understood only when integrated with any carrier

Comment: We are far from being used Einstein's equations, we are still in the derivative stage