# Energy-momentum tensor conservation?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, conservation-laws, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

In [General Relativity Lecture Notes by Javier Rubio, Chapter 6-Einstein Equations](https://javierrubioblog.files.wordpress.com/2015/12/chapter6.pdf) we read

> **6.1 The energy-momentum tensor**
>
> $\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots$
>
> **6.2 The microscopic description**
>
> The relation between $\;\rho\;$ and $\;p\;$ is usually characterized by an equation of state $\;p=p(\rho)\;$ which depends on the microscopic particles involved in the fluid. In order to get some insight about the possible equations of state, let me consider a macroscopic collection of N structureless point particles interacting through spatially localized collisions. The energy density associated to any of them is given by
> \begin{equation}
> T^{00}_{n}=E_{n}\delta^{(3)}\left(\mathbf x-\mathbf x_n\left(t\right)\vphantom{A^2}\right)=m_{n}\gamma_{n}\delta^{(3)}\left(\mathbf x-\mathbf x_n\left(t\right)\vphantom{A^2}\right)\,, 
> \tag{6.19}\label{6.19} 
> \end{equation}
> with $\;\gamma_n=1/\sqrt{1-\upsilon^2_n\,}\;$ and $\;n=1,...,N\;$ a label selecting the particular particle we are referring to. Taking into account the identity
> \begin{align}
> \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\!\!\mathrm d\tau\,\delta^{(4)}\left(x-x\left(\tau\right)\vphantom{A^2}\right) & = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\!\!\mathrm d\tau\,\delta\left(t-t\left(\tau\right)\vphantom{A^2}\right)\delta^{(3)}\left(\mathbf x-\mathbf x\left(\tau\right)\vphantom{A^2}\right)
> \nonumber\\
> & = \dfrac{\mathrm d\tau}{\mathrm dt}\delta^{(3)}\left(\mathbf x-\mathbf x\left(t\right)\vphantom{A^2}\right)=\dfrac{1}{\gamma}\delta^{(3)}\left(\mathbf x-\mathbf x\left(t\right)\vphantom{A^2}\right)\,,
> \tag{6.20}\label{6.20} 
> \end{align}
> the non-Lorentz invariant 3-dimensional Dirac delta appearing in equation \eqref{6.21} can be transformed into
> a Lorentz invariant 4-dimensional Dirac delta<sup>5</sup>
> \begin{equation}
> T^{00}_{n}=m_{n}\!\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\!\!\mathrm d\tau_n\,u^0_n u^0_n\,\delta^{(4)}\left(x-x_n\left(\tau_n\right)\vphantom{A^2}\right) \,. 
> \tag{6.21}\label{6.21} 
> \end{equation}
> The same procedure can be applied to the spatial momentum density (or energy current) of the particle
> \begin{equation}
> \begin{split}
> T^{0i}_{n}&=p^i_n\,\delta^{(3)}\left(\mathbf x-\mathbf x_n\left(t\right)\vphantom{A^2}\right)\\
> &=m_n\gamma_n\upsilon^i_n\,\delta^{(3)}\left(\mathbf x-\mathbf x_n\left(t\right)\vphantom{A^2}\right)=E_n\upsilon^i_n\,\delta^{(3)}\left(\mathbf x-\mathbf x_n\left(t\right)\vphantom{A^2}\right)\,,\\
> \end{split}
> \tag{6.22}\label{6.22} 
> \end{equation}
> and to the flux of the $\,i\,$ momentum component in the $\,j\,$ direction (or viceversa)
> \begin{equation}
> T^{i j}_{n}=p^i_n\upsilon^j_n\,\delta^{(3)}\left(\mathbf x-\mathbf x_n\left(t\right)\vphantom{A^2}\right)=p^j_n\upsilon^i_n\,\delta^{(3)}\left(\mathbf x-\mathbf x_n\left(t\right)\vphantom{A^2}\right)\,.
> \tag{6.23}\label{6.23} 
> \end{equation}
> We obtain
> \begin{equation}
> \begin{split}
> T^{0i}_{n}&=m_{n}\!\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\!\!\mathrm d\tau_n\,u^0_n u^i_n\,\delta^{(4)}\left(x-x_n\left(\tau_n\right)\vphantom{A^2}\right) \,,\\
> T^{i j}_{n}&=m_{n}\!\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\!\!\mathrm d\tau_n\,u^i_n u^j_n\,\delta^{(4)}\left(x-x_n\left(\tau_n\right)\vphantom{A^2}\right) \,.\\
> \end{split}
> \tag{6.24}\label{6.24} 
> \end{equation}
> Equations \eqref{6.21} and \eqref{6.24} can be rewritten in a very compact way in terms of the stress-energy-momentum tensor $\,T^{\mu\nu}_n\,$
> \begin{equation}
> \begin{split}
> T^{\mu\nu}_n &=m_{n}\!\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\!\!\mathrm d\tau_n\,u^\mu_n u^\nu_n\,\delta^{(4)}\left(x-x_n\left(\tau_n\right)\vphantom{A^2}\right)\\
> &=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\!\!\mathrm d\tau_n\dfrac{p^\mu_n p^\nu_n}{m_{n}}\,\delta^{(4)}\left(x-x_n\left(\tau_n\right)\vphantom{A^2}\right) \,,\\
> \end{split}
> \tag{6.25}\label{6.25} 
> \end{equation}
> which is manifestly symmetric and Lorentz invariant since $\,u^\mu_n u^\nu_n\,$ is a tensor under Lorentz transformations and both $\,m_{n}\,$ and $\,d\tau_n\,u^\mu_n u^\nu_n\,\delta^{(4)}\left(x-x_n\left(\tau_n\right)\vphantom{A^2}\right)\,$ are Lorentz scalars. The total energy density of the
> whole system of particles can be written as the sum of the individual contributions, namely
> \begin{equation}
> T^{\mu\nu}=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N}T^{\mu\nu}_n \,.
> \tag{6.26}\label{6.26} 
> \end{equation}

> **6.2.1 Energy-momentum tensor conservation and geodesics**
>
> Let us see under which conditions the total energy momentum tensor (6.26) is conserved. Taking the derivative with respect to the coordinates we get
> \begin{equation}
> \partial_\mu T^{\mu\nu}=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N}m_{n}\!\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\!\!\mathrm d\tau_n\,u^\mu_n\, u^\nu_n\,\partial_\mu\,\delta^{(4)}\left(x-x_n\left(\tau_n\right)\vphantom{A^2}\right)\,,
> \tag{6.27}\label{6.27} 
> \end{equation}
> which using
> \begin{equation}
> \begin{split}
> u^\mu_n\partial_\mu\,\delta^{(4)}\left(x-x_n\left(\tau_n\right)\vphantom{A^2}\right)&=\dfrac{\mathrm d x^\mu_n}{\mathrm d\tau_n}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x^{\mu}}\,\delta^{(4)}\left(x-x_n\left(\tau_n\right)\vphantom{A^2}\right)\\
> &= -\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d\tau_n}\left[\delta^{(4)}\left(x-x_n\left(\tau_n\right)\vphantom{A^2}\right)\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\right] \,,\\
> \end{split}
> \tag{6.28}\label{6.28} 
> \end{equation}
> can be written as
> \begin{equation}
> \begin{split}
> \partial_\mu T^{\mu\nu}=&-\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N}m_{n}\!\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\!\!\mathrm d\tau_n\,\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d\tau_n}\left[u^{\nu}_{n}\delta^{(4)}\left(x-x_n\left(\tau_n\right)\vphantom{A^2}\right)\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\right]\\
> &+\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N}m_{n}\!\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\!\!\mathrm d\tau_n\, \dot u^\nu_n\,\delta^{(4)}\left(x-x_n\left(\tau_n\right)\vphantom{A^2}\right)\,.\\
> \end{split}
> \tag{6.28a}\label{6.28a} 
> \end{equation}
> The first term in the right hand side of the previous expression disappears in the particles are stable,
> i.e. if the orbits are closed or come from negative infinite time and disappear into positive infinite
> time. We are left then with the second term, which can be written as
> \begin{equation}
> \partial_\mu T^{\mu\nu}=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\!\!\mathrm d\tau_n\dfrac{\mathrm d p^\nu_n}{\mathrm d\tau_n}\delta^{(4)}\left(x-x_n\left(\tau_n\right)\vphantom{A^2}\right)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N}\dfrac{\mathrm d p^\nu_n}{\mathrm d t}\delta^{(3)}\left(\mathbf x-\mathbf x_n\vphantom{A^2}\right)\,,
> \tag{6.29}\label{6.29} 
> \end{equation}
> with $\,p^\nu_n=m_n u^\nu_n\,$ the 4-momentum of the individual particles. The *local energy momentum conservation* $\,\partial_\mu T^{\mu\nu}=0\,$ requires the particles to be free. Or in other words, the condition $\,\partial_\mu T^{\mu\nu}=0\,$ is equivalent to the geodesic equation in Minkowski space-time, $\,\mathrm d p^\mu_n/\mathrm d\tau =0\,$. This will be also the case in curved spacetime.

$\text{------------------------------------------------------------------------------------}$

<sup>5
The fact that the 4-Dimensional Dirac delta $\;\delta^{(4)}\left(x\right)\;$  is Lorentz invariant follows directly from the definition $\;\int\mathrm d^4x\delta^{(4)}=1\;$ and the fact that the volume element $\;\mathrm d^4x\;$ is Lorentz invariant.</sup>

$\text{------------------------------------------------------------------------------------}$

I don't see how we got equation \eqref{6.27}. And how after using equation \eqref{6.28} we get equation \eqref{6.28a}?

Also for the  \eqref{6.28} equation, can someone explain to me how this simplification can be done?

Comment: Please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563/168783), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/479421) instead.

Comment: this is from this chapter: https://javierrubioblog.files.wordpress.com/2015/12/chapter6.pdf   page 6-7

Comment: i am trying to write it in code but don't want to work...( i am surely writing things wrong but don't know where...)

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Equivalence of the geodesic equation and the continuity equation for the energy-momentum tensor](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/303773/2451)

Answer (score 2):

You missed a $\partial_{\mu}$ in (6.27).  It should be
\begin{equation}
\partial_\mu T^{\mu\nu}=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N}m_{n}\!\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\!\!\mathrm d\tau_n\,u^\mu_n u^\nu_n\,\partial_{\mu}\delta^{(4)}\left(x-x_n\left(\tau_n\right)\vphantom{A^2}\right)\,,
\tag{6.27} 
\end{equation}
and it can be obtained directly from (6.25) and (6.26).

To get (6.28), the identities
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\mu}} F(x-x_{n}) = - \frac{\partial}{\partial x_{n}^{\mu}} F(x-x_{n})
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\frac{d x_{n}^{\mu}}{d\tau_{n}} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_{n}^{\mu}} = \frac{d}{d\tau_{n}}
\end{equation}
have been used.

To get (6.28a), the identity
\begin{equation}
- u_{n}^{\nu} \frac{d}{d\tau_n}\left[\delta^{(4)}\left(x-x_n\left(\tau_n\right)\vphantom{A^2}\right)\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\right] = - \frac{d}{d\tau_n}\left[u_{n}^{\nu} \,\delta^{(4)}\left(x-x_n\left(\tau_n\right)\vphantom{A^2}\right)\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\right] + \dot u^\nu_n\,\delta^{(4)}\left(x-x_n\left(\tau_n\right)\vphantom{A^2}\right)
\end{equation}
and integration by parts have been used.