# Covariant derivative of tensor

Tags: homework-and-exercises, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, geodesics

> I want to show that on a geodesic we have for a particle
>   $$\nabla_mT^{mn}=0$$
>   where
>   $$T^{mn}=\frac{m}{\sqrt{-g}}\int d\tau~ u^mu^n\delta^4(x-x(\tau)).$$

So I found

$$\nabla_mT^{mn} =\partial_mT^{mn}+\Gamma^m_{ml}T^{ln}+\Gamma^m_{ml}T^{ln}\\
\partial_m\left(\frac{m}{\sqrt{-g}}\int d\tau ~u^mu^n\delta^4(x-x(\tau))\right)
=\frac{m}{\sqrt{-g}} \times \\
\int d\tau \left[(\partial_mu^m)u^n\delta^4(x-x(\tau))+
u^m(\partial_mu^n)\delta^4(x-x(\tau))+u^m u^n \partial_m\delta^4(x-x(\tau))\right]$$

How do I continue from here? I know that I will eventually need to use the geodesic equation and the $\delta^4(x-x(\tau))$ term will cancel stuff. But how do I use these things here?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/39526/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/303773/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Exact duplicate of [Derivation of the geodesic equation from the continuity equation for the energy momentum tensor -](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/303773/)